# Why my application is crashing? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: c++, arrays, crash

```
char* szWords[] = { "caralho", "porra" };
if (IsGoldGrade(pObj)) //Ignore, its ok. //Crashing after i added the
{
    for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(szWords); x++) {
        if (strstr((strlwr((char*)szWords[x])), szChat)) {
            char szBuffer[256]; 
            sprintf(szBuffer, "You can't type %s", szWords[x]);
            Announce(pObj, szBuffer);
            memset(szBuffer, 0, 256);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Idk but I can't use this as "code" on stackoverflow.

Pastebin: http://pastebin.com/u8yit8Rw

PS: I can't use StrStrI because im using Visual Studio 2003.

Comment: At least tell us what the error is...

Comment: Hello. Im using at server on my game. The error is, my game crashing when this function is executed.

Comment: The file on Pastebin contains words which are probably prohibited by Stack Overflow. Remove those words and you should be able to paste the whole code into your question.

Comment: Yes, and when it crashes it is because of an error. You have to tell us what that error is if you want us to help.

Comment: This looks like a problem which would vanish if you're permitted to replace `char *` with `std::string`.

Comment: @takendarkk I can't see the error. My matchserver just crashed.

Comment: @JackDeeth thank you for reply. I tried std but I don't know how to use 'for' for strings. Can you make a example for me?

Comment: Your debugger will tell you exactly what the error is, and provide a stack trace.

Comment: Is this a profanity filter? What are you trying to create? And why do you have so many bad words in your code? Lol.

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson hahaha. This is badwords filter for my game. Thank you for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop condition is wrong. You want to iterate the array of pointers to char.
Your loop `for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(szWords); x++)` continues while `x < sizeof(szWords)`. But `sizeof(szWords)` is **not** array length. It just says how many bytes your array occupies in memory. It is system dependant, however it is twice the size of pointer to char, so probably 8 or 16 bytes. You need to divide this size by size of the array element then you will get the proper array size.

Rewrite your `for` loop like this:

`for (int x = 0; x < sizeof(szWords)/sizeof(szWords[0]); x++)`

or if your compiler supports C++11 you can try range-based for:

`for (const char *word : szWords)`

Apart from that, if you are writing C++ code you really should use STL and other C++ features. For instance your array of strings should be declared as:

`std::vector<std::string> words = { "caralho", "porra" };`

or if your compiler doesnt support C++11 (then really change it...)

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
words.push_back("caralho");
words.push_back("porra");

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < words.size(); ++i) {
    // since you are using C string functions you will need word as C string
    const char *word = words[i].c_str();
    // do whatever you want with word
}
```

Also consider reading modern C++ book before writing code.

Comment: Thank you ! I gonna test it now.

Comment: Can you recommend for me a modern c++ book? Thanks.

Comment: @Lcs Check this topic for book recommendations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 1):

From the look of it, this is a function which checks if the user has written a prohibited word?

I'd replace `char* szWords[]...` with `std::vector<std::string>` to store the prohibited words, and use `std::find` to see if the input is in that list.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<std::string> bannedWords{"hamster", "elderberries", "etcetera"};

bool isBanned(const std::string &str) {
  return std::find(bannedWords.begin(), bannedWords.end(), str) != bannedWords.end();
}

int main() {
  std::cout << "Is 'wally' banned? " << isBanned("wally") << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Is 'elderberries' banned? " << isBanned("elderberries") << std::endl;
}
```

More information about `std::find` is [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

[Here's an online demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/9V9gMam7oAKveykR)

Comment: Thanks my friend. But im using VS 2003 and that doens't allows I use your functions.

Comment: @Lcs Ah - I'd overlooked that. Sorry!

Comment: @Lcs Try now - `auto` might not be VS 2003-compatible but `string`, `vector` and `find` all should be!

Comment: Thanks friend. Do you recommend for me a modern book? I need update myself lol. I even don't know that there is auto

Comment: There's two classic books by Scott Meyers: "Effective C++", written in the VS 2003 era and largely applicable today, and "Effective Modern C++", covering what's changed and what's new. There's some great videos on YouTube too, hiding among many very in-depth and opaque videos :)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I'll see soon. More one time, thanks :)